# How can I get values from CKEditor and display them in an HTML table?

Tags: jquery, html, ckeditor

[image]

i have to show  equation from editor to the following table as it is

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content from ckeditor, by the following piece code. You need to place the id associated to your html element in place of `<id-for-the-textarea>` in the provided code.
`CKEDITOR.replace()` will replace the textarea having id passed to it earlier with a CKEDITOR functional text box. After that you can get the text by calling `CKEDITOR.instances` on the id of the html element that CKEDITOR had override.

```
var msgEditor = CKEDITOR.replace('<id-for-the-textarea>', {
        height: "150",
        // placeholder:'Type text...',
        //extraPlugins: 'placeholder',
    });
var msg = CKEDITOR.instances.<id-for-the-textarea>.document.getBody().getHtml();
```

In order to get only the equation from the text received, you can use

```
msg.replace("solve this mathematical equation", "");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.